# how to read and write in canvas by using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, html5-canvas

i want to automate read and write into console which is made of canvas element in web application. how to do this by using selenium java.

my canvas elelment

`

```html
<canvas id="console" height="200" width="200" 
                    style="border:1px solid green"> 
 </canvas>
```

`

Comment: You can't do it like this. You need to see if the Javascript that writes to that canvas has certain methods that you can use for sending text

Comment: @TarunLalwani there is no javascript method used to write in console which is in canvas element. HTML5 viewer data  may be not send data by javascript.